# Swift 3 `presentViewController` error

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift3

At the moment I´m learning to code with Xcode and Swift. Therefore I copied the project from [this Apple Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1)

In the tutorial I am asked to use `presentViewController`.

Using Swift 3 the `presentViewController` method isn't being populated by Xcode's IntelliSense to fill the function. (as seen in the image below)

[image: Image from apple tutorial]

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

It will present a view controller modally. `imagePickerController` is the view controller instance, second parameter is animation parameter(whether you want to present controller with animation or no), last parameter is `completion block`.

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 3 thing changed. You were using presentViewController and sending the view controller as an argument. Apple wants it to be clear. For example, the new way is to use and implement methods like `present(imagePickerController...` rather than the old look.